# Is it possible to access parent object from its property?

Tags: objective-c

Is it possible to access parent object from its property?

In this simple application I have a window which responds to keypress events.
I want my property object named "window" to set its parent object "AppDelegate" variable "upKeyPressed" to a value when event occurs.
Is it possible in any way?

AppDelegate.h:

```
@interface MyWindow : NSWindow
@end

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
{
    BOOL upKeyPressed;
}
@property (assign) IBOutlet MyWindow *window;
@end
```

AppDelegate.m file:

```
@implementation MyWindow

- (void)moveUp:(id)sender
{
    // here I want to set upKeyPressed value to YES with a kind of:
    self.parentObject->upKeyPressed = YES; // *** fantasy command
}

@end

@implementation AppDelegate
...
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no concept of parents when it comes to properties. What you want to do is add `@property (assign) AppDelegate *parentObject;` (you can call it what you want) to your `MyWindow` class's interface. Then synthesize it in your implementation.

For it to work, you also need to set it to point to your app delegate - in your `-applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` add `self.window.parentObject = self;`. Then to access the so-called "parent" object from your `MyWindow` instance, just use `self.parentObject`.

Edit: You need to forward-declare `AppDelegate` by putting `@class AppDelegate;` before your interface definition for `MyWindow`.